# Combined bar and line chart with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting 2 series as bars and one as line with ggplot, but line chart is not visible somehow. Can't figure out the error. And also I want to add labels to bars and lines.

```
dput(data_plot)

structure(list(career_level = structure(c(5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
8L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("Executives", 
"Head of Organization", "Management-NonSales", "Management-sales", 
"Overall", "Para-Professional- Blue Collar", "Para professional -white collar", 
"Professional- Sales", "Professional-Non Sales"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("actual_2018", 
    "budget_2019"), class = "factor"), value = c(5.3, 5.1, 5, 
    3.3, 5.3, 2.2, 2.3, 2.2, 2.2, 5.3, 5.1, 5, 3.3, 5.3, 2.2, 
    2.3, 2.2, 2.2)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")

dput(forecast)
structure(list(career_level = structure(c(5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
8L, 9L, 7L, 6L), .Label = c("Executives", "Head of Organization", 
"Management-NonSales", "Management-sales", "Overall", "Para-Professional- Blue Collar", 
"Para professional -white collar", "Professional- Sales", "Professional-Non Sales"
), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "forecast_2020", class = "factor"), 
    value = c(5.3, 5.1, 5, 3.3, 5.3, 2.2, 2.3, 2.2, 2.2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")



ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=data_plot,aes(x=career_level,y=value,fill=variable),stat="identity",position = "dodge")+
  geom_point(data=forecast,aes(x=career_level,y=value))+
  geom_line(data=forecast,aes(x=career_level,y=value,colour=variable))
```

I want the forecast as a line on the the graph.

Also I was trying this code for labels but it giving combined label on bars, not separate labels, I want separate labels on both bars and the line too:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=data_plot,aes(x=career_level,y=value,fill=variable),stat="identity",position = "dodge")+
    geom_text(data=data_plot, aes(x=career_level,y=value,label = paste0(value, "%")),face= "bold",color="#FDFEFE",size=3,position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  geom_point(data=forecast,aes(x=career_level,y=value))+
  geom_line(data=forecast,aes(x=career_level,y=value,colour=variable,group=1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add grouping aesthetic in `geom_line`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
geom_bar(data=data_plot, aes(x=career_level,y=value,fill=variable),
          stat="identity",position = "dodge")
geom_point(data=forecast,aes(x=career_level,y=value)) +
geom_line(data=forecast,aes(x=career_level,y = value,colour=variable, group = 1))
```

[image]

To get the labels we can do

```
ggplot(data_plot) +
   aes(x=career_level,y=value,fill=variable) +
   geom_bar(,stat="identity",position = "dodge") +
   geom_text(aes(label=paste0(value, "%")), 
        position=position_dodge(width = 1), vjust=-0.5)  +
   geom_point(data=forecast,aes(x=career_level,y=value)) + 
   geom_line(data=forecast,aes(x=career_level,y=value,colour=variable,group=1)) + 
   geom_text(data = forecast, aes(x=career_level,y=value,label=paste0(value, "%")), 
          position=position_dodge(width =1), vjust= -2.5)
```

You might need to adjust the height and width of labels to make the labels visible.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Also I need to add labels to all series as percentages

Comment: @SandhyaGhildiyal Labels as percentage of what? From `data_plot` or `forecast` ? We can use `geom_text` to add labels.

Comment: These values are already percent values I am just adding % to the numbers.I want separate labels on bars and the line. Bars are based on data_plot and line is on forecast. I was trying this code but it giving combined label on bars, not separate labels, I have edited the question

Comment: @SandhyaGhildiyal I updated the answer to plot `labels`.

Comment: I adjusted width and height of labels and it looks fine, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way by combining the two datasets. This can save typing `x` and `y` in each `aes`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

combined <- rbind(data_plot, forecast)

ggplot(data = combined, aes(x = career_level, y = value, group = variable)) + 

  # Add bar for actual and budget
  geom_bar(data = combined[combined$variable != "forecast_2020",], stat = "identity", position = "dodge", aes(fill = variable)) +

  # Add point and line for forecast
  geom_point(data = combined[combined$variable == "forecast_2020",]) +
  geom_line(data = combined[combined$variable == "forecast_2020",]) + 

  # Add % labels # EDITED TO keep one decimal place and font size smaller
  geom_text(aes(x = career_level, y = value, label = percent(value/100, accuracy = 0.1), group = variable), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.5, size = 3)
```

Comment: One way you could do to make labels not appear to be overlapping is to only keep 1 decimal place using `accuracy = 0.1` and also make font size smaller by `size = 3`.